# How to find the formula by name in excel macros

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the exel document, where have a macros and formulas. Can't share the document because it's contains the confidential info. Was searched in web but don't found anything.

In one cell I have the following formula: `=method1!F3`

Is anybody know where can I found this formula and value? Because I dont have the sheet with name `method1`.

Also I have a sheet in document which dont have any cells at all. Is it the special sheet for macrosses?

Comment: Does this formula returns a value? It might sound silly but did you check the hidden sheets of your workbook?

Comment: You can also select your cell, and click on Trace Precedents in the Formulas tab of the ribbon. An arrow appears, double-click on it and you can go to the location of method!F3

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the sheet is hidden or very hidden. In case sheet is just hidden then you can I hide it, if the sheet is very hidden the follow these steps:

1
Open the excel file and use the shortcut alt+f11 to enter the vba project, on the top right screen you can see all the sheets in the current wb.

2 
To unhide the sheet use the below code

```
Sub unhide()

    Thisworkbook.sheets("method1").visible=xlsheetvisible

End sub
```